# Assertion 'ia_addressID' failed while starting weblogic/OCCAS

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic-10.x, jrockit

I have installed OCCAS 5.1 (wlserver_10.3) and created a domain.
I am using jrockit-jdk1.6.0_45-R28.2.7-4.1.0.

When I am starting the weblogic, I am getting the below error.

As some answers suggested, I have also configured `<listen-address>host_ip</listen-address>`, but no luck.

Did anybody face this issue? It works when I use Open JDK

```
[root@localhost bin]# ./startWebLogic.sh
.
.
JAVA Memory arguments: -Xms512m -Xmx512m
.
WLS Start Mode=Development
.
CLASSPATH=/root/Oracle/Middleware/patch_wls1036/profiles/default/sys_manifest_classpath/weblogic_patch.jar:/root/Oracle/Middleware/patch_occas510/profiles/default/sys_manifest_classpath/weblogic_patch.jar:/root/jrockit-jdk1.6.0_45-R28.2.7-4.1.0/lib/tools.jar:/root/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic_sp.jar:/root/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.jar:/root/Oracle/Middleware/modules/features/weblogic.server.modules_10.3.6.0.jar:/root/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/webservices.jar:/root/Oracle/Middleware/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.1/lib/ant-all.jar:/root/Oracle/Middleware/modules/net.sf.antcontrib_1.1.0.0_1-0b2/lib/ant-contrib.jar:/root/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/sip/server/lib/weblogic_sip.jar:/root/Oracle/Middleware/occas_5.1/server/lib/platform/occas_depended.jar:/root/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/common/derby/lib/derbyclient.jar:/root/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/xqrl.jar
.
PATH=/root/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/bin:/root/Oracle/Middleware/modules/org.apache.ant_1.7.1/bin:/root/jrockit-jdk1.6.0_45-R28.2.7-4.1.0/jre/bin:/root/jrockit-jdk1.6.0_45-R28.2.7-4.1.0/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin
.
***************************************************
*  To start WebLogic Server, use a username and   *
*  password assigned to an admin-level user.  For *
*  server administration, use the WebLogic Server *
*  console at http://hostname:port/console        *
***************************************************
starting weblogic with Java version:
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Oracle JRockit(R) (build R28.2.7-7-155314-1.6.0_45-20130329-0641-linux-x86_64, compiled mode)
Starting WLS with line:
/root/jrockit-jdk1.6.0_45-R28.2.7-4.1.0/bin/java -jrockit   -Xms512m -Xmx512m -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer -Djava.security.policy=/root/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/weblogic.policy  -Dwlss.maddr.enable=true -Xverify:none -ea:com.bea.wcp...   -da -Dplatform.home=/root/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3 -Dwls.home=/root/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server -Dweblogic.home=/root/Oracle/Middleware/wlserver_10.3/server   -Dweblogic.management.discover=true  -Dwlw.iterativeDev= -Dwlw.testConsole= -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole= -Dweblogic.ext.dirs=/root/Oracle/Middleware/patch_wls1036/profiles/default/sysext_manifest_classpath:/root/Oracle/Middleware/patch_occas510/profiles/default/sysext_manifest_classpath  weblogic.Server
<May 5, 2014 4:23:50 PM IST> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090905> <Disabling CryptoJ JCE Provider self-integrity check for better startup performance. To enable this check, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification=true>
<May 5, 2014 4:23:50 PM IST> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090906> <Changing the default Random Number Generator in RSA CryptoJ from ECDRBG to FIPS186PRNG. To disable this change, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultPRNG=true>
<May 5, 2014 4:23:50 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000395> <Following extensions directory contents added to the end of the classpath:
/root/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/jsr_test/lib/sipactivator.jar>
<May 5, 2014 4:23:50 PM IST> <Info> <Server> <BEA-002647> <The service plugin, com.oracle.core.sip.activator, was added from /root/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/jsr_test/lib/sipactivator.jar.>
<May 5, 2014 4:23:50 PM IST> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000377> <Starting WebLogic Server with Oracle JRockit(R) Version R28.2.7-7-155314-1.6.0_45-20130329-0641-linux-x86_64 from Oracle Corporation>
<May 5, 2014 4:23:51 PM IST> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141107> <Version: WebLogic Server 10.3.6.0  Tue Nov 15 08:52:36 PST 2011 1441050 >
<May 5, 2014 4:23:53 PM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING>
<May 5, 2014 4:23:53 PM IST> <Info> <WorkManager> <BEA-002900> <Initializing self-tuning thread pool>
<May 5, 2014 4:23:54 PM IST> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320400> <The log file /root/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/jsr_test/servers/AdminServer/logs/AdminServer.log will be rotated. Reopen the log file if tailing has stopped. This can happen on some platforms like Windows.>
<May 5, 2014 4:23:54 PM IST> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320401> <The log file has been rotated to /root/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/jsr_test/servers/AdminServer/logs/AdminServer.log00004. Log messages will continue to be logged in /root/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/jsr_test/servers/AdminServer/logs/AdminServer.log.>
<May 5, 2014 4:23:54 PM IST> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170019> <The server log file /root/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/jsr_test/servers/AdminServer/logs/AdminServer.log is opened. All server side log events will be written to this file.>
java: Net.c:229: Java_com_bea_wcp_sctp_Net_initIDs: Assertion `ia_addressID' failed.
./startWebLogic.sh: line 180: 29436 Aborted                 (core dumped) ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java ${JAVA_VM} ${MEM_ARGS} -Dweblogic.Name=${SERVER_NAME} -Djava.security.policy=${WL_HOME}/server/lib/weblogic.policy ${JAVA_OPTIONS} ${PROXY_SETTINGS} ${SERVER_CLASS}
[root@localhost bin]#
```

Below is the AdminServer.log

```
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:29 AM IST> <Info> <Security> <localhost.localdomain> <> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1399343309486> <BEA-000000> <Disabling CryptoJ JCE Provider self-integrity check for better startup performance. To enable this check, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification=true> 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:29 AM IST> <Info> <Security> <localhost.localdomain> <> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1399343309960> <BEA-000000> <Changing the default Random Number Generator in RSA CryptoJ from ECDRBG to FIPS186PRNG. To disable this change, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultPRNG=true> 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:29 AM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <localhost.localdomain> <> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1399343309977> <BEA-000000> <Following extensions directory contents added to the end of the classpath:
/root/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/jsr_test/lib/sipactivator.jar> 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:30 AM IST> <Info> <Server> <localhost.localdomain> <> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1399343310133> <BEA-000000> <The service plugin, com.oracle.core.sip.activator, was added from /root/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/jsr_test/lib/sipactivator.jar.> 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:30 AM IST> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <localhost.localdomain> <> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1399343310162> <BEA-000000> <Starting WebLogic Server with Oracle JRockit(R) Version R28.2.7-7-155314-1.6.0_45-20130329-0641-linux-x86_64 from Oracle Corporation> 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:30 AM IST> <Info> <Management> <localhost.localdomain> <> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1399343310588> <BEA-000000> <Version: WebLogic Server 10.3.6.0  Tue Nov 15 08:52:36 PST 2011 1441050 > 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:32 AM IST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <localhost.localdomain> <> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1399343312365> <BEA-000000> <Server state changed to STARTING> 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:32 AM IST> <Info> <WorkManager> <localhost.localdomain> <> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1399343312373> <BEA-000000> <Initializing self-tuning thread pool> 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:33 AM IST> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <localhost.localdomain> <> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1399343313104> <BEA-000000> <WebLogic Server "AdminServer" version:
WebLogic Server 10.3.6.0  Tue Nov 15 08:52:36 PST 2011 1441050  Copyright (c) 1995, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.> 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:33 AM IST> <Notice> <Log Management> <localhost.localdomain> <> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1399343313211> <BEA-170019> <The server log file /root/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/jsr_test/servers/AdminServer/logs/AdminServer.log is opened. All server side log events will be written to this file.> 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:33 AM IST> <Info> <Log Management> <localhost.localdomain> <> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <> <> <1399343313219> <BEA-170023> <The Server Logging is initialized with Java Logging API implementation.> 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:33 AM IST> <Info> <Diagnostics> <localhost.localdomain> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1399343313283> <BEA-320001> <The ServerDebug service initialized successfully.> 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:33 AM IST> <Info> <Server> <localhost.localdomain> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1399343313348> <BEA-002622> <The protocol "t3" is now configured.> 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:33 AM IST> <Info> <Server> <localhost.localdomain> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1399343313348> <BEA-002622> <The protocol "t3s" is now configured.> 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:33 AM IST> <Info> <Server> <localhost.localdomain> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1399343313348> <BEA-002622> <The protocol "http" is now configured.> 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:33 AM IST> <Info> <Server> <localhost.localdomain> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1399343313349> <BEA-002622> <The protocol "https" is now configured.> 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:33 AM IST> <Info> <Server> <localhost.localdomain> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1399343313349> <BEA-002622> <The protocol "iiop" is now configured.> 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:33 AM IST> <Info> <Server> <localhost.localdomain> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1399343313350> <BEA-002622> <The protocol "iiops" is now configured.> 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:33 AM IST> <Info> <Server> <localhost.localdomain> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1399343313350> <BEA-002622> <The protocol "ldap" is now configured.> 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:33 AM IST> <Info> <Server> <localhost.localdomain> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1399343313351> <BEA-002622> <The protocol "ldaps" is now configured.> 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:33 AM IST> <Info> <Server> <localhost.localdomain> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1399343313352> <BEA-002622> <The protocol "cluster" is now configured.> 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:33 AM IST> <Info> <Server> <localhost.localdomain> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1399343313353> <BEA-002622> <The protocol "clusters" is now configured.> 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:33 AM IST> <Info> <Server> <localhost.localdomain> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1399343313356> <BEA-002622> <The protocol "snmp" is now configured.> 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:33 AM IST> <Info> <Server> <localhost.localdomain> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1399343313356> <BEA-002622> <The protocol "admin" is now configured.> 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:33 AM IST> <Info> <Server> <localhost.localdomain> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1399343313357> <BEA-002624> <The administration protocol is "t3s" and is now configured.> 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:33 AM IST> <Info> <Server> <localhost.localdomain> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1399343313361> <BEA-002622> <The protocol "sip" is now configured.> 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:33 AM IST> <Info> <Server> <localhost.localdomain> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1399343313361> <BEA-002622> <The protocol "sips" is now configured.> 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:33 AM IST> <Info> <Server> <localhost.localdomain> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1399343313362> <BEA-002622> <The protocol "sips-admin" is now configured.> 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:33 AM IST> <Info> <Server> <localhost.localdomain> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1399343313365> <BEA-002622> <The protocol "diameter" is now configured.> 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:33 AM IST> <Info> <Server> <localhost.localdomain> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1399343313366> <BEA-002622> <The protocol "diameters" is now configured.> 
####<May 6, 2014 7:58:33 AM IST> <Info> <Server> <localhost.localdomain> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1399343313366> <BEA-002622> <The protocol "diameter-sctp" is now configured.>
```

Comment: Any other details in `/root/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/jsr_test/servers/Admi/root/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/jsr_test/servers/AdminServer/logs/AdminServer.log`?

Comment: I could not see anything specific. There is no error. Added the AdminServer.log in the main question.

Comment: Can you try without jrockit just to see if a normal jdk works? You may need to set your `JAVA_VENDOR` environment variable to `Sun` rather than `Oracle`

Comment: As i mentioned earlier, It works when I use Open JDK. Also I have tried with `JAVA_VENDOR` as `Sun`, but still the problem exists.

Comment: The problem is solved after applying few patches on OCCAS 5.1. I think these patches are available only via oracle support

Answer (score 4):

Just to clarify.

1. $BEA_HOME/wlserver_10.3/sip/server/native/.../.../libsctpwrapper.so is a library just used in context of Diameter communication and you can safely delete it in case you are not using SCTP communication to a Diameter node.

So in case this API means nothing to you, make a backup and delete/remove access rights to the .so file for your platform.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E27702_01/doc.51/e36938/com/bea/wcp/diameter/package-frame.html

The preferred way is to install latest patches.

2. What does this error mean?

The error itself is not specific to this library. It can be seen in other 3rd party libraries as well. The short story is that current versions of JDKs are more strict in how to code JNI calls. This was introduced with JDK 1.6.0_65 for v6 addresses and JDK 1.6.0_45 for v4 addresses. So saying "OpenJDK does not crash" means that OpenJDK does not do those additional tests.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification